# Item count for longlistselector on windows phone 7?

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-phone-7

I dont see `lls.items.count` for LongListSelector.

How do i get the item count from LLS without group headers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `LongListSelector` class uses the `ItemsSource` to hold the underlying collection the selector is displaying.  It's declared as an `IEnumerable` so you should be able to obtain the count using the `Count()` extension method.  It will need to be cast to a generic enumerable first (using `Cast<>()`).

Try this:

```
var count = lls.ItemsSource.Cast<object>().Count();
```

Comment: That one did not work. it says "Count is a not a member of System.Collections.IEnumarable.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I was referring to the WP8 version of the selector, not the WP7 toolkit version.  We'll have to make a few adjustments.